# Coldfusion load animation cfform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coldfusion

I have been looking everywhere for a loading animation.  I need it to show while this page is loading and then stop/hide it when the page is done loading.

I already have a loading gif image. Just not sure where to go from here.

```
 <cfform action="submitform.cfm" method="POST">
   <!--- Code Here  --->

   <input type="Image" src="../images/btn_submit.gif" border="0" alt="Submit" style="border: none;">

 </cfform>
```

I have Coldfusion 11.

Comment: Don't use `cfform` (or any other ColdFusion UI functionality). They are poorly implemented, often times uneccessarily complex, and have limited functionality. Use a plain old HTML `<form>` and if you need some of the extra bells and whistles, use a JavaScript library like jQuery and its plethora of plugins to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This does not pertain to ColdFusion per se. IF you are trying to implement a conventional "wait" spinner, pick one of the many many implementations of loaders and spinners and immitate it.

This link, titled [Loaders and spinners](http://codepen.io/collection/HtAne/), will show snippets of HTML, JS and CSS you need to emulate to get it done. But it's really a JS thing not a CF thing.

Typically a spinner works with AJAX - not a "page load" so much as an HTTP request made *by* the page and the page where you tell the user to wait a sec. If you are really jumping from one page to the next the you might add your css and JS to put the spinner on the page and then use `<cfflush>` to push the "partial" HTML to the browser where the JS fires and does it thing, then use "onLoad" to remove the spinner. We *used* to do such things back in the day before Ajax and all these wonderful libraries for handling content. :) It's a kludge though.

Another choice was to go to an intermediat page where the spinner is spinning while a background process requests status of the server. When the server returns a status of "ok" (or order processed or image handled or whatever) then the page would redirect to the final content page. Again, neither of these approaches is elegent on todays web.